# How can I load and then print multiple numbers if their quantity is determinted by the input and not by variables

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVgTK.png)

how can I do this using scanf funtion ranging form -1000 to 1000 ?
just %d numbers

Comment: Loop until `scanf` return value is less than 1?

Comment: Can we have a little more information? Like what errors are you getting? Can we see some code to make this a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I neeed to make a program which behaves like the image

Comment: which means input would be for example 3 4 5 8 and it would give me 3 4 5 8 again as an output

Comment: What if you do a loop with a `scanf` and `printf`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Ian Abbott
 thank u mate

Comment: @FourBars
 yep just couldnt figure this out, making my third program in shcool and I wasnt paying attention :D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SajLenc I've answered your question. Check the answer and, if it doesn't solve your problem, tell us more information about what you need. I'll edit my answer to fit exactly what you're asking for when you clarify it.

Comment: also any ideas how to remove coma from the last number ? like this input 4 5 3 1  output 4, 5, 3, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dooing a loop with a `scanf` and a `printf` inside, like this:

```
int num = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   scanf("%d", &num);
   printf("%d", num);
}
```

You just need to change the `5` to the number of iterations you need.

Comment: Please read the manual for `scanf` - It does return a value that is useful

Comment: @EdHeal yes I know. I'm just trying to interpret what he needs, because it's not so clear, so I gave him this answer to see if it's useful for him or we should change it to fit his needs. Its hard to help if the question is not easy to understand.